# Error al usar helper DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Tengo una base de datos con sedes, las cuales recupero para guardarlas en una base de datos de carteleras. Uso DropDownList para recuperar los valores, pero al intentar guardar me dice:

> Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'. No hay ningún elemento
>   ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable' con la clave 'IdSede'.
>   Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web
>   actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información
>   acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código.
>
> Detalles de la excepción: System.InvalidOperationException: No hay
>   ningún elemento ViewData de tipo 'IEnumerable' con la
>   clave 'IdSede'.
>
> Error de código fuente:
>
> Línea 18:                  Línea 19:
>   Sede Línea 20:
>   @Html.DropDownList("IdSede", null, "Selecione Sede", new { @class =
>   "form-control" }) Línea 21:
>   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdSede, "", new { @class =
>   "text-danger" }) Línea 22:

**Controlador**:

```
public ActionResult NuevoCartelera()
        {
            ViewBag.IdSede = new SelectList(db.Sedes, "IdSede", "Nombre");
            ViewBag.IdPelicula = new SelectList(db.Peliculas, "IdPelicula", "Nombre");
            ViewBag.IdVersion = new SelectList(db.Versiones, "IdVersion", "Nombre");
            return View();
        }

     [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NuevoCartelera(Carteleras Cartelera)
    {
        Carteleras car = new Carteleras();
        car.IdSede = Cartelera.IdSede;
        car.IdPelicula = Cartelera.IdPelicula;
        car.HoraInicio = Cartelera.HoraInicio;
        car.FechaInicio = Cartelera.FechaInicio;
        car.FechaFin = Cartelera.FechaFin;
        car.NumeroSala = Cartelera.NumeroSala;
        car.IdVersion = Cartelera.IdVersion;
        car.Lunes = Cartelera.Lunes;
        car.Martes = Cartelera.Martes;
        car.Miercoles = Cartelera.Miercoles;
        car.Jueves = Cartelera.Jueves;
        car.Viernes = Cartelera.Viernes;
        car.Sabado = Cartelera.Sabado;
        car.Domingo = Cartelera.Domingo;            

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Carteleras.Add(car);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Carteleras"); // Retorna a la vista "Peliculas"
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**Vista**:

```
    model Cinemania.Carteleras

@{
    Layout = "/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdministracion.cshtml";
}
        <div class="container">
            @*using (Html.BeginForm("/NuevoPelicula", "Administracion", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "text-danger" }))*@

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div id="loginbox" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">

                <!-- CABECERA -->
                <h2 class="text-center">Nueva cartelera</h2>

                <!-- INPUT NOMBRE -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Sede">Sede</label>
                    @*Html.DropDownList("IdSede", null, "Selecione Sede", new { @class = "form-control" })*@

                    @Html.DropDownList("IdSede", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.IdSede, "Selecione Sede", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdSede, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

</div>

                <!-- INPUT DESCRIPCION -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="Sede">Pelicula</label>

                    @Html.DropDownList("IdPelicula", null, "Selecione Pelicula", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdPelicula, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <!-- INPUT CALIFICACION -->

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HoraInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.HoraInicio, new { @class = "form-control horario time ui-timepicker-input" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HoraInicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="lunes">Lunes</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("lunes", true)

                    <label for="martes">Martes</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("martes", true)

                    <label for="miercoles">Miercoles</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("miercoles", true)

                    <label for="jueves">Jueves</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("jueves", true)

                    <label for="viernes">Viernes</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("viernes", true)

                    <label for="sabado">Sabado</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("sabado", true)

                    <label for="domingo">Domingo</label>
                    @Html.CheckBox("domingo", true)
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaFin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaFin, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FechaInicio, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FechaInicio, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FechaInicio, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- INPUT DURACION -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="sala">Numero de sala</label>
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NumeroSala, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NumeroSala, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="version">Version</label>
                    @Html.DropDownList("IdVersion", null, "Selecione version", new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdVersion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>
                <!-- BOTON GUARDAR -->
                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Guardar" />

                    <!-- LINK SALIR -->
                    <a href="./Peliculas" class="btn btn-default">Cancelar</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        }
    </div>




        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/jquery.timepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Fecha.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/Horario.js"></script>


</body>
</html
```

**Modelo**:

```
namespace Cinemania.Models
{
    public class CarteleraMetaData
    {

        public int IdCartelera { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe elegir una sede")]
        public int IdSede { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe elegir una pelicula")]
        public int IdPelicula { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar la hora de inicio")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"^(0[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5][0-9] [AP]M$", ErrorMessage = "Se debe seleccionar un horario válido")]
        public string HoraInicio { get; set; }
        /*  public TimeSpan _HoraInicio
          {
              get
              {
                  try
                  {
                      DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(HoraInicio);
                      return dt.TimeOfDay;
                  }
                  catch
                  {
                      return new TimeSpan();
                  }
              }
          }*/

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar la fecha de inicio")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaInicio { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar la fecha de fin")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/mm/yyyy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaFin { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar el numero de sala")]
        public int NumeroSala { get; set; }
        public bool Lunes { get; set; }
        public bool Martes { get; set; }
        public bool Miercoles { get; set; }
        public bool Jueves { get; set; }
        public bool Viernes { get; set; }
        public bool Sabado { get; set; }
        public bool Domingo { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Debe indicar la version de la pelicula")]
        public int IdVersion { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tengo los otros `DropDownList` que andan perfectamente.

Comment: Tu código de la vista no corresponde con el error que muestras. No tiene siquiera un DropDownList para IdSede

Comment: recien veo el mensaje, la vista no era la correcta, ya la corregí

Answer (score 0):

Muy probablemente

```
ViewBag.IdSede = new SelectList(db.Sedes, "IdSede", "Nombre");
```

Te debe de estar regresando una lista nula (que no es lo mismo que vacía). Verificar por esa parte.

Comment: la lista me devuelve los datos almacenados de la base de datos

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en que el atributo que recoges como valor en tu dropdown no existe en la clase osea:

```
ViewBag.IdSede = new SelectList(db.Sedes, "IdSede", "Nombre");
```

esto quiere decir que Debes tener una clase Sede con IdSede como llave y un string Nombre. De no ser así revisa la clase Sede y fijate bien en su llave puesto que si está definida como

```
public int Id { get; set; }
```

tu ViewBag debe quedar asi

```
 ViewBag.IdSede = new SelectList(db.Sedes, "Id", "Nombre");
```